# How to call a java class in a karate feature file?

Tags: karate

I have a requirement where I need to run 1 line of code extra in karate if today is the end of a month.
For this, I need to get the system date using java code and then fetch the result to my feature file.

Can someone help me how to do this?

Comment: please read the docs, it will save you a lot of time: https://github.com/intuit/karate#calling-java